# disparity between PHP version run at CLI and version installed by brew

Tags: php, macos, installation

I have the following problem on my MacBook

`which php` shows `/usr/bin/php` (read-only)
`php --version` shows

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.29-to-be-removed-in-future-macOS (cli) (built: Aug 30 2021 10:56:16) ( NTS )
```

However, when I run `brew upgrade PHP`, it tells me:

```
Warning: php 8.1.1 already installed
```

and indeed I find directory  `/usr/local/etc/php/8.1`

In theory I could set a symlink in `/usr/bin/php8 -> path to that binary`

But:

1. there is no binary in that 8.1 folder and
2. `/usr/bin/` appears to be write only

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized later that I could resolve this with the `/usr/local/bin` folder versus the `/usr/bin` folder.  In fact, that gave away the location of the PHP binary for 8.1:

```
ls -la /usr/local/bin
#following:
# ...
# lrwxr-xr-x    1 oliverwilliams  admin      27 Jan 10 19:33 php -> ../Cellar/php/8.1.1/bin/php
# ...
mv /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php8
```

In my mind this is not a perfect solution as I would have preferred to either delete the global php install and alias the `/usr/local/bin` php globally, or rename the global php to `php73` as well for legacy.